# iPhone Accelerometer calibration

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, calibration

How do I properly calibrate the accelerometer for my iPhone game? Currently, when the phone is on a flat surface, the paddle drifts to the left. High or Low Pass filters are not an acceptable solution as I need complete control over the paddle even at low & high values. I know Apple has the BubbleLevel sample but I find it difficult to follow... could someone simplify the process?

My accelerometer code looks like this:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

float acelx = -acceleration.y;
float x = acelx*40;

Board *board = [Board sharedBoard];
AtlasSprite *paddle = (AtlasSprite *)[board.spriteManager getChildByTag:10];

if ( paddle.position.x > 0 && paddle.position.x < 480) {
    paddle.position = ccp(paddle.position.x+x, paddle.position.y);
}

if ( paddle.position.x < 55 ) {
    paddle.position = ccp(56, paddle.position.y);
}

if ( paddle.position.x > 435 ) {
    paddle.position = ccp(434, paddle.position.y);
}

if ( paddle.position.x < 55 && x > 1 ) {
    paddle.position = ccp(paddle.position.x+x, paddle.position.y);
}

if ( paddle.position.x > 435 && x < 0) {
    paddle.position = ccp(paddle.position.x+x, paddle.position.y);
}
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, problem SOLVED and the solution is so simple I'm actually embarrassed I didn't come up with it sooner. It's as simple as this:

In a "Calibration Button":

```
//store the current offset for a "neutral" position
calibration = -currentAccelX * accelerationFactor;
```

In the game time accelerometer function:

```
//add the offset to the accel value
float x = (-acceleration.y * accelerationFactor) + calibration;
```

It's as simple as adding the offset. * *hides his head* *

Comment: Here's a comprehensive explanation of the subject http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/39833-tutorial-accelerometer-calibration-optimizations.html

Comment: This is an old thread but I am curious to what type of objects currentAccelX is and what accelerationFactor is. Can you assist with this?

Comment: Yeah, where did you get those vars; currentAccelX and accelerationFactor?  This post was old back in 2011...i know its even older now but perhaps someone can help me? thx

Comment: This is the code I have so far:                                       //calibrate code from StackOverflow
    float calibration = -acceleration.x * accelerationFraction;
    float x = (-acceleration.y * accelerationFraction) + calibration;
    
    accelerationFraction = acceleration.y*2;
    if (accelerationFraction < -1) {
        accelerationFraction = -1;
    } else if (accelerationFraction > 1) {
        accelerationFraction = 1;
    }
    //API CHANGE set delegate to self
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        accelerationFraction *= -1;
    }

Comment: read my explanation here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/39833-tutorial-accelerometer-calibration-optimizations.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have so far:

```
//calibrate code from StackOverflow
float calibration = -acceleration.x * accelerationFraction;
float x = (-acceleration.y * accelerationFraction) + calibration;

//My original code
accelerationFraction = acceleration.y*2;
if (accelerationFraction < -1) {
    accelerationFraction = -1;
} else if (accelerationFraction > 1) {
    accelerationFraction = 1;
}
//API CHANGE set delegate to self
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    accelerationFraction *= -1;
}
```